# Palindrome string program

Tags: c++, strings, palindrome

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>





using namespace std;




string reversal(string a) {
    int i = a.length();
    string reversed_string{}; 
    for (; i >= 0; --i) 
         reversed_string += a[i];
    
    
    

    return reversed_string;

}




bool palindrome(string a) {


    
     if (a == reversal(a)) {
        
         cout << "this is a palindrome " << endl;
        return true;
     }
     else if(a != reversal(a))
     {

         cout << "this is not a palindrome " << endl;
         return false;
     }





}




int main(){




}
```

> This is my program for the palindrome program, finding the reverse of a string was the less tedious part however the palindrome function does not work ,and i don't understand why.

Comment: Missing consistent formatting and includes. Try to make it a complete compiling program...

Comment: @Deduplicator done

Comment: `main()` doesn't seem to call any of the functions you defined.  You could omit them without changing the observable results.

Comment: *when you are paid per line of code*

Comment: Unfortunately this question is _off-topic_ because this site is for reviewing **working** code. Please [take the tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up at our [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). When the code works then feel free to [edit] the post.

Answer (score 2):

The large amounts of whitespace don't improve readability.  A *single* blank line between functions would be fine, and occasional single empty lines anywhere else it's necessary to separate logical groups.

Avoid `using namespace std;`.  It can cause surprise overloads, and makes code harder to read (because it's no longer evident where identifiers come from).

`reversal()` could be made more efficient by using `reserve()` to ensure the result string has the right capacity from the start.  That said, it's simpler to use the string's *reverse iterators* to construct the reversed string:

```
std::string reversed_string{a.rbegin(), a.rend()};
```

But we don't actually need to allocate a new string and copy into it.  If we use the `std::equal()` algorithm, we can just pass the two iterator pairs:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

```
if (std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(),  a.rbegin(), a.rend())
```

Since C++20, we have been able to use Ranges to get a reverse-view of a string and compare it:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
```

```
if (std::ranges::equal(a,  a | std::ranges::reverse))
```

Predicate functions are normally named beginning with `is_` or `has_` - here, we'd write `is_palindrome()`.  We don't need our own copy of `a`, so pass by const reference.

Prefer not to produce output in a predicate function - just return the result.  The caller might choose to print the result, or use it for something else.  When you do produce output, don't flush the stream without good reason - i.e. prefer `'\n'` to `std::endl`.

We certainly don't need to reverse `a` twice - the `else if` can be plain `else`.  More simply, as both branches simply return true or false respectively, we can just return the comparison result:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string& a)
{
    return std::ranges::equal(a, a | std::views::reverse);
}
```

This is still doing more work than necessary, since we only need to compare the first half of the string to the last half (continuing beyond that point is redundant).  So we can just compare the first `size() / 2` elements, by using a sub-range view (`std::views::take`).

---

Here's where we end up - no `std::string`s created, and no unnecessary comparisons:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <string_view>

bool is_palindrome(const std::string_view a)
{
    auto const halflen = a.size() / 2;
    return std::ranges::equal(a | std::views::take(halflen),
                              a | std::views::reverse | std::views::take(halflen));
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (auto const& s: { "", "0", "abc", "racecar" }) {
        std::cout << '"' << s << "\" "
                  << (is_palindrome(s) ? "is a palindrome" : "is not a palindrome")
                  << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `auto const half = std::views::take(a.size() / 2); return std::ranges::equal(a | half, a | std::views::reverse | half);` look better?

Comment: I'm not convinced that's clearer, but it's certainly an option to consider.